# Custom CSS in Wordpress not working

Tags: css

I've struggled with this problem with a while and still couldn't find the solution.
I've created custom CSS box for my posts in wordpress, but the thing is, it is not working. Box doesn't show up, no matter what I do.

Was hoping if someone could see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Style:

```
.square880x165 {
margin: 10px auto;
display: block;
width: 880px;
height: 165px;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
float:left;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #aaaeaf), color-stop(100%, #689ecd));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#aaaeaf, #689ecd);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#aaaeaf, #689ecd);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#aaaeaf, #689ecd);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#aaaeaf, #689ecd);
background-image: linear-gradient(#aaaeaf, #689ecd);
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-ms-border-radius: 4px;
-o-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1 3px rgba(0, 0, .35);
box-shadow: 0 1 3px rgba(0, 0, .35);
background: white;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-ms-border-radius: 2px;
-o-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
bottom: 1px;
content: '';
left: 1px;
right: 1px;
top: 1px;
```

}

and HTML:

```
<div class="square880x165"><p>test</p></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can make an example with jsfiddle

Comment: No problem with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML and CSS look like they should work (there is repetition in the CSS but that won't stop it working). Have you put them both in the right place in your Wordpress theme?

The CSS usually goes in style.css and make sure the page with the HTML is referencing that stylesheet.

Have you got a live page we can view?

---

Okay, based on your test code, this issue is with how you've embedded your styles.  I looks like you've just pasted them into the post, so Wordpress has automatically added paragraph tags in-between the CSS, which breaks it.  Here's a snippet:

```
<style>
<p>body{
    background: #fff;
    color: #4A4A4A ;
}</p>
<p>.square880x165 {
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;

    position: relative;}</p>
</style>
```

You need to paste you CSS directly into style.css., so in your WP dashboard click on **Appearance** then **Editor**, paste the CSS directly into the stylesheet and click **Update File**.

Comment: I've included CSS into post.

Here is a test page:
http://www.lbaudio.org/test-2/

Comment: Great this works, but the biggest problem is, that i would like to use boxes on couple of posts and I wouldn't like to have paragraphs and headings affected.
I would also like to have different size of boxes (square880x165, square300x200, square180x50....), which would be resized to provide best estetics.
Is there any way, I could insert this CSS into specified posts?

Comment: Have a look at this plugin which might help - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-css-stylesheet-for-posts-or-pages/